# Matlab interp3 function in C#.NET

Tags: c#, matlab, math, interpolation, ilnumerics

I want to use matlabs `interp3` function in c#, or any `class`, `dll` ,etc that can do the same thing.
I can not use `ILnumerics`, and also `Math.Net numerics`, does not the task completely.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Matlab you can create a dll and then use in c# ImportDll to read the matlab.

Comment: Dear Biguri
Thank you for your answer, my program needs to be completely independent from Matalb....

Comment: The dll created by matlab uses the runtime library which does not require a license.  So it is independent from Matlab.

Comment: Why not use ILNumerics? Its interp3 does pretty much the same? If you cannot use ILNumerics how can you use another 3rd-party library?

Comment: Dear Biguri, can you help me with the process of converting matlab function to DLLs?